# Referencing classes in other files

Tags: javascript

I need 4 arguments, name times instructorName and instructorDept, then instance variables name, times and instructor, name needs to be a string with default "unknown course name" and time "unknown times", which is all fine, but the place where I'm lacking information is instructor needs to be an instance of a class called Faculty that I have in another .js file with no default, constructed using new and the Faculty constructor, then need a getter and setter where setinstructor() takes an instance of Faculty as its parameter, and getinstructor() returns an instance of faculty.

Looking through whats been provided to me, I haven't seen anything on this, so I'm unsure of what to do

```
class Course {
    constructor(name, times, instructor) {   
        this.name = name || "unknown course name";
        this.times = times || "unknown times";
        this.instructorName = instructor;
        this.instructorDept = instructor;
        }



    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    getTimes() {
        return this.times;
    }

    getInstructor(){
        return;
    } //Placeholder

    setName(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    setTimes(times) {
        this.times = times;
    }

    setInstructor(instructor){
        ;
    } //Placeholder
}
```

The overall goal of this file is to get it to where if it was used in another file for like

```
document.writeln( "New course: " + crs1.getname() + 
                  ", " + crs1.gettimes() +
                  ", " + crs1.getinstructor() + "<br>" );
```

it would spit out "New course: unknown course name, unknown times, name unknown of department unknown"

Comment: Is this homework? Looks like the task is to just complete what is currently being done for `name` and `times`, i.e add the default, getter and setter's, where *Placeholder* is. Else you need to make it more clear what you are trying to achieve, where is Faculty?

Comment: Well it is homework but the task was to make three different files from what we've been outlined to do, which I did all of of the other 2 files, but I wasn't sure how to do the parts where I put placeholder, which I put to show where I'm struggling at

Comment: Also this file and the Faculty file are made only to be used in the main.js file, so everything else is done as it should be I believe, beyond the instructor portion.

Comment: The only diff is Faculty would be an object, so you dont set/default it to a string else its going to bork when its set as an object, it should prob be an instance of an empty Faculty object.

Comment: I'm relatively new to javascript, can you give an example of that?

Comment: `this.instructorDept = instructor || new Faculty();` - now you just need to require/import Faculty, if you dont want that dependency in the file, then throw an exception, so the caller must pass it.

Comment: i.e what params are defined in the constructor are "dependencies". If the class does not need it right away, define empty in construct then just use setter/getters (though its not private, so you might as well use `crs1.name` etc).

Comment: So I tried to import faculty.js
`import {Faculty} from './faculty.js';`
but it gives me this SyntaxError: Unexpected token {